# Circle cut in the middle of the nav bar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

So I have a figma prototype to follow and they want me to make a cut in the middle of the nav bar like this :
The Figma : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJIHa.png)

That is the code that I have so far :

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");

.wrapper {
  border: solid 0.25rem black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2vmin;
  position: relative;
  width: 40vh;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar img {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.navbar a[href="/search"] {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.navbar a[href="/notes"] {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(128, 131, 255, 0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 20px solid var(-clr);
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(
      270deg,
      rgba(227, 224, 243, 0.245) 0%,
      rgba(128, 131, 255, 0.255) 100%
    ),
    #8083ff;
}

a[href="/feeds/buckets?show=inprogress"] img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.top_buttons {
  margin-top: 45px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 35px;
}

.friends,
.for_you {
  font-family: "Opens Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #8083ff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.friends {
  background-color: #8083ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.for_you {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #8083ff;
}

.post {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
}

.post p {
  font-family: "Opens Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.post p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.user-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.user-picture {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.username {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 19px;
}

.post p:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.post-content {
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.posts-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: calc(80vh - 230px);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.create_post {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.user-input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.user-avatar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.create_post::placeholder {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style_friendspost.css" />
    <script defer src="myscripts.js"></script>
    <title>Main Feed</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top_buttons">
        <p>Cheer Your Friends!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="posts-container">
        <% feed.forEach(post => { %>
        <div class="post">
          <div class="user-picture"></div>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p class="username">@<%=post.username%></p>
            <p><%= post.completed[0] %></p>
            <p><%= post.bucketName[0] %></p>
            <p><%= post.messages %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% }) %>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <a href="/feeds/home">
          <img
            src="../styles/images/home_icon_noBackground.png"
            alt="Home"
            width="40"
            height="40"
          />
        </a>
        <a href="/search">
          <img
            src="../styles/images/search_icon_noBackground.png"
            alt="Search"
            width="40"
            height="40"
          />
        </a>
        <div class="circle">
          <a href="/feeds/buckets?show=inprogress">
            <img
              src="../styles/images/bucket_icon_noBackground.png"
              alt="Bucket"
              width="50"
              height="50"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
        <a href="/notes">
          <img
            src="../styles/images/note_icon_noBackground.png"
            alt="Notes"
            width="40"
            height="40"
          />
        </a>
        <a href="/profile">
          <img
            src="../styles/images/profile_icon_noBackground.png"
            alt="Profile"
            width="40"
            height="40"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone knows how to do it or using css or bootstrap ?

Im expecting to someone to know how to achive the figma prototype style